# Not able to add UIImageView as a subView of a UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a single view application.  I have a UIView that is centred X and Y to the superview.  I am trying to programmatically as a UIImageview to the UIView using autolayout.  My image fails to appear anywhere in the UIView.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var popUpContainer: UIView!

 let image = UIImage.init(named: "tickok")
 let imageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
 self.popUpContainer.addSubview(imageView)

 // THIS ENABLES THE AUTOLAYOUT CONSTRAINT FOR IMAGEVIEW
 imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.popUpContainer.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
  imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
  imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.popUpContainer.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Comment: What is the Y constraint for `imageView`? Does `popUpContainer` have a non-zero width and height?

Comment: popUpContainer has width of 200 and height 150

Comment: are these line inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: @dean Ok good, and are you giving it a Y constraint? X, Width, and Height is not enough for Autolayout. For example, include `imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.popUpContainer.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: @JakeG you are correct. after adding your suggestion i can now see the image. thank you. if you would like to add the above as an answer I can accept it

Comment: @dean Awesome, glad it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a Y-constraint as well - X, Width, and Height is not enough for auto layout. So either `centerYAnchor` or a `topAnchor` or `bottomAnchor`.

For example, include `imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.popUpContainer.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`